# Can't boot into fastboot from Error Mode screen

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, system-error

I have a Huwaei P9 Lite (2017) with unlocked bootloader, build number PRA-LX1C432B172. Both recovery partitinons probably got damaged and the phone just hangs in the Error Mode screen (just like in the photo attached). Rebooting and pressing any combination of buttons just causes it to go into that screen. If I discharge the battery completely, it will boot into system, but I forgot the password (stupid me). Now even when I am in the system, I can't use *adb reboot fastboot*, because USB debugging isn't enabled (ADB doesn't even see the phone), so all I can do is turn it off/reboot it, it then goes into Error Mode screen, then wait for it to discharge and I am at the beginning again.

What I've tried so far:

- Pressing volume down (or up or both) and Power when in Error Mode screen -> just reboots into Error Mode again
- When completely off (discharged), pressing vol. down and quickly inserting the cable into the PC -> boots into system
- When completely off (discharged), pressing vol. up or both and power -> goes into Error Mode
- When completely off (discharged), inserting charging cable -> after a while, it boots into system
- When in system, *adb reboot fastboot* -> no way, can't even see it using *adb devices*
- Connecting it to HiSuite both in Error Mode and system -> it doesn't see anything

Data in the phone is my main concern. All I really need is one time fastboot access, I can figure the rest out on my own then

[image]